# Shell prompt does not shows on socket

Tags: c, shell, sockets, io-redirection, stderr

I want to establish a remote shell over tcp.

I already got it to work, but there's a small issue:
The prompt does not shows up on client side.

If my client input `echo hi`, it well prints `hi` on stdout (client side), and the shell process remains open until he hits `ctrl-D` or chooses to exit whatever way.

After some basic investigation, I figured out that bash prints its prompt on stderr (e.g. `bash 2>/dev/null` will not show any prompt on any terminal).

This may be a hint but before I call `execve` in the shell process, I do my redirections from my server to my client connection fd this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dup2(client->confd, i);
}
execve("/bin/bash", (char *[]){"bash", NULL}, NULL);
```

And as my server's stdout (1) is well redirected to my client connection fd, stderr (2) should too. I'm I right?

I don't know how to fix it, any help would be very appreciated.

### More context:

- If I input an invalid command on client side, a message well appears, meaning stderr is redirected.
- If I redirect stderr to stdout before my redirections on server side, and then redirects stdin / stdout to my client connection fd, nothing changes.
- I connect clients to my server this way: `nc localhost 8080`.
- I close all open file descriptors that are greater than 2 before my redirections.
- `isatty(client->fd)` returns 0, so maybe she shell's prompt isn't shown on non tty descriptors, but can't find any clue in readline code or wherever else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man bash:

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option whose  standard  input  and
> error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.

A non-interactive shell normally won't print the prompt at all.

Comment: Thanks, starting bash with the `-i` option did the trick.